# Weird frozen edge of window after animation

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls, storyboard, transition

ok, am I the only person who runs into stuff like this?  I have a simple Storyboard:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="slideInStoryboard" >
    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:.75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="1,0,0,0" DecelerationRatio=".9" />
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" />
</Storyboard>
```

and I instantiate and run it from the CodeBehind for page-transitioning:

```
       private void ShowModule(string currentModule)
    {
        Storyboard sIn = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("slideInStoryboard");
        Storyboard sOut = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("slideOutStoryboard");

        foreach (UserControl uc in ModulesPanel.Children)
        {
            if (uc.Name == currentModule)
            {
                uc.BeginStoryboard(sIn);
            }
            else
            {
                uc.BeginStoryboard(sOut);
            }
        }            
    }
```

The slideOutStoryboard is identical but opposite direction.  It looks fine.  Everything seems to work as expected, EXCEPT:  when the containing Window is expanded (as it starts out by default), any controls within the left 2 inches or so of the screen don't respond to clicks or anything.  If I grab the left margin of the window and move it to the right a couple of inches, I can then click inside those textboxes and click the arrows of the comboboxes, etc.etc.  As soon as I grab that left margin and drag it back to the left, they stop working again.  They almost seem disabled, but not greyed out.  If I remove the animations, there is no problem with anything.

Yes, I'm definitely a newbie, but I sure can't figure how I've rendered the left side of my screen unresponsive!  Any assistance at all, even suggested hints, are welcome!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `FillBehavior="Stop"` to your xaml storybord and see if that helps. e.g. `<Storyboard x:Key="slideInStoryboard" FillBehavior="Stop" >`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to have any effect at all except to make the UserControl disappear after the animation.